# Open file dowloaded through URL

Tags: vba, excel

I am crafting a reporting platform for my sales team, we use Saleforce.com (SFDC) as our CRM.

I have figured out how to create the link that triggers the download. Example of [the link](https://my.salesforce.com/00O860000069Bf6?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=xls).

If I navigate to this link, it will automatically trigger the download.

I want to :

1. navigate to this link through VBA, trigger the download,
2. change the save name
3. open the file to execute additional code on it (mainly to extract the data).

I am currently playing around with something that looks like this

```
sub extractData ()
Dim filePath as String

filePath = "https://my.salesforce.com/00O860000069Bf6?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=xls"
Workbooks.Open(filePath)

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your problem? does the link open the file? if not, what error is returned? if no error, make sure you have set `Application.DisplayAlerts=True`. Have you tried downloading this very same URL with cURL?

Comment: Thanks. My problem is I don't know exactly how to have VBA trigger the download and save the file to further open. If I was to, for example, follow the link on a browser it will download the file, the following steps would be manual though (open the file, extract the data, etc.), I want to automate this process. 

I am not familiar with cURL.

Comment: cURL is a command line downloader, I mentioned as a way to check that the file can be downloaded. One trick is to use google chrome developer tools, point to that url, and have chrome to build the cURL command for you, complete with all the appropiate http headers.

Comment: Does your downloads always goes to the same folder? I'd be good to write properly your issue, that I guess is to **find the file after downloading it**, in order to open it and work with it. Am I right?

Comment: It does, always save to the same folder. I'm a not too concerned about that. It is more something of triggering the download and renaming the file to a standard name (given it downloads with a report serial number ie, report 10223221232).

Comment: What is it you are exporting from salesforce a report? Can you not use the API to pull the data directly rather than trying to hit that URL then extracting the data you want from a pre compiled sheet?

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid I have no idea where to begin working with the API. I am extracting an opportunity report through the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sebastian,

Like Dan said, it might be easier to pull the specific text/data from the page than downloading it first. If you want to do this I can help, but can only offer a generic code with the information given.